# Rails: Association between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to Rails so not everything is very clear to me. I have the following models.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sales
   belongs_to :user
end
```

---

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :brands
   belongs_to :warehouse
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :order
end
```

---

What I want to do is to connect those 2 models, so every Sale has a parent Order_ID. How would you do this in your controller? I'm confused. Thank you guys!

Comment: Doing a belongs_to will give you the order_id field. Now all you have to do is set it in your sales_controller create action.

Comment: The two models are already connected with setting you have here so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look up how to create a [`has_many/belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) association:

[image]

To get what you want, you'd use the following:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sales
end

#app/models/sale.rb
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
end
```

You'll need to set the `foreign_key` of the `Sale` model, so that each time you invoke a `@sale` object, it will be associated to an `@order`:

```
$ rails g migration AddForeignKeyToSales

#db/migrate/add_foreign_key_to_sales________.rb
class AddForeignKeyToSales < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
       change_table :sales do |t|
         t.references :order, after: :id
       end
   end
end 

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will set the sale table to include the `order_id` foreign key, which you can then use with the following controller setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :orders do
   resources :sales #-> url.com/orders/:order_id/sales/new
end

#app/controllers/sales_controller.rb
class SalesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @order = Order.find params[:order_id]
      @sale = @order.sales.new
   end

   def create
      @order = Order.find params[:order_id]
      @sale = @order.sales.new order_params
      @sale.save
   end
end
```

Comment: @harakiri : Have look at this solution given by  Rich Peck, I think you wont get anything better than this solution.